# Как сделать команду в дискорд боте, которая принимает на вход файл

Tags: python, бот, discord.py, discord

Как сделать команду которая принимает файл(изображение) сохраняет его в папке, или сохраняет его url?
Подразумевается такое использование:
`>test (прикреплено изображение)`
и программа допустим сохраняет в переменную `data` url адрес этого изображения или сохраняет его в папке с программой в png или jpg файл

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У класса [**`discord.Message`**](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=message#discord.Message)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

есть атрибут [**`attachments`**](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=message#discord.Message.attachments)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

хранящий список прикрепленных к этому сообщению файлов в виде экземпляров класса [**`discord.Attachment`**](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=message#discord.Attachment)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

у которого, в свою очередь есть атрибуты:

- [**`content_type`**](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=message#discord.Attachment.content_type), хранящий в виде строки тип файла в формате [`Media type`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type)
- [**`filename`**](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=message#discord.Attachment.filename) — имя прикрепленного файла
- [**`url`**](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=message#discord.Attachment.url) — ссылка на файл

и другие, про которые можно также почитать в документации.

---

Далее, из контекста `ctx` получаем объект сообщения `ctx.message`, а из него список его файлов `ctx.message.attachments`.

Фильтруем список по типу файлов, чтобы там остались только изображения и, если список не пустой, то сохраняем все файлы и отправляем сообщение.

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='>', intents=discord.Intents.all())

@bot.command(name='test')
async def test(ctx: commands.Context) -> None:
    images = [file for file in ctx.message.attachments if 'image' in file.content_type]

    if not images:
        return await ctx.reply('Прикрепите изображение(я)')

    for image in images:
        with open(image.filename, 'wb') as image_file:
            await image.save(image_file)

    await ctx.reply(f'Сохраненные изображения: ' + ', '.join(f'[{image.filename}](<{image.url}>)' for image in images))
    
    
bot.run('TOKEN')
```

**Результат:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

В документации есть вся информация. По возможности, старайтесь сначала самостоятельно изучать содержимое классов, с которыми вы можете работать, обрабатывая команды.

На всякий случай, вот [**руководство по работе с документацией**](https://github.com/denisnumb/discord-py-guide/blob/main/using_docs.md#%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-discord-py)

Comment: Сэр, по всем моим Discord.py вопросам почти всегда отвечаете Вы. Причем на вопросы любой сложности и характера. Вы что разработчик Discord.py?)

Comment: @MCSasha я так развернуто отвечаю как раз таки для того, чтобы показать, что ответы на все ваши вопросы уже есть в документации)

Comment: вы прямо PRO программист, даже документацию читаете и понимаете)